# На чем лучше написать серверную часть

Tags: php, javascript

Я новичок самоучка  в программировании, хочу создать нормальный планировщик задач, но при этом одним из главных требований является то что страница не должна перезагружаться совсем. Из готовых инструментов у меня более менее PHP и JS и немного AJAX, вопрос в следующем:

1) на чем лучше писать серверную часть на PHP или стоит изучить Node.js?
2) если я например (пока изучаю Node.js) напишу сервер на PHP, смогу ли я потом переписать его на Node.js и внедрить так чтобы пользовательская инфа не пострадала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока у вас есть весь стек чтобы создать нормальный планировщик задач. Впрочем, от мысли изучить **NodeJS** отказываться не надо, это мощный инструмент, который в умелых руках будет показывать лучший результат чем **PHP**. Также поскольку вы хотите чтобы страница не перезагружалась, вы будете использовать **Ajax** и тут я ещё советую изучить вам, асинхронное обращение к веб-серверу как теорию, ибо практикой будет использования **Ajax**.

Comment: ок спасибо за ответ, а можете ответить на второй ответ, при написанном сервере на PHP у меня будет возможность переписать его на Node без ущерба пользовательской информации (то есть чтобы пользователь особо ничего не заметил)

Comment: Ну конечно, главное ведь не код, а сам замысел, что должен делать сервер, остальное вы просто реализуете на той технологии которую знаете.

Comment: благодарю. буду пробывать